# how to send message to mobile phones from localhost wamp server

Tags: php, localhost, message, wampserver

I want to send messages to mobile phones using wamp server in php.I need this so i can send message to my user's phone when they login to my site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sms gateway in php for send sms to mobile...!

Try google search for sms gateway for php...!

Thanks...!